# Laravel 8 returns 403 UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS

Tags: php, laravel, acl, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8, and I have a resource Controller named `Profile`. And within this Controller, users can edit their user profile information.

So at the `edit` method, I put this:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('edit-user', $user);
        
    return view('editprofile', compact('user'));
}
```

And users can access `editprofile` blade by this button:

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.edit' , ['profile' => Auth::user()->id]) }}" class="btn">Edit Profile</a>
```

But now the problem is, it returns this:

**403 THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED.**

However I am already logged in and I want to access my own `profile.edit` and not other users!

So if you know why am I getting this error, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks.

And here is also my route:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('profile' , ProfileController::class);
});
```

> **UDPATE 1:**

[image: capture]

Comment: `$this->authorize('edit-user', $user);` this is not working i guess can u add your policy code ?

Comment: You may try this `User $profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the followings

- Route parameter names is "profile"
  So, the controller method parameter must be the same "$profile".

```
public function edit (Request $request, User $profile) {
    Gate::allows('edit-user', $profile);

    // do the logic
}
```

Comment: Would you tell me how?

Comment: @POOYAA can you tell how you have implemented the auth ? is it session ? have you enabled session middleware in the web group ?

Comment: May be the session middleware is not enabled. You are authorizing on the previous controller and it is not persisting in the app as in the next request, it is not showing. Can you execute this and tell me if user is coming in dd($request->user()) in edit method ?

Comment: I just used that default `auth` middleware from kernel.php for redirecting user back to login page if not logged it

Comment: I added `$request->user();` to `public function edit(Request $request,User $user)` method, and it prints empty screen!

Comment: dd($request->user()); please write this
It should show user object in black screen. if prints null, then authorization is not done.

If user comes, please check if it is the same user you are passing from the route

Comment: I just added a picture of result at the question, thanks,

Comment: have you defined the authorization gate rule "edit-user" ? can you share it also ?

Comment: At `AuthServiceProvider`: `Gate::define('edit-user',function($user, $currentuser){
           return $user->id == $currentuser->id;
        });`

Comment: I have modified answer please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229138/discussion-between-pooyaa-and-s-k-r).

Answer (score 2):

i had the same error. i changed

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

to

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

in `App\Http\Requests\StoreProductRequest`